# Double scrollbar on embeded facebook timeline iframe (cross-domain)

Tags: css, facebook, iframe, cross-domain

Trying to embed a facebook timeline but get a double scrollbar as can be seen here.
[image]

When I try to do anything to it I get cross domain errors.  Is there anything I can do to get rid of the scrollbar on the right or am I stuck with it?

Comment: Looks like it displays like this for all pages at the moment. So go file a bug report, and ask them to fix it. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Same issue with me since last night and adding FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(); doesnt help :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted a bug report on Facebook. They marked the bug as invalid and stealth fixed the issue.